# How do I apply one onClickListener to multiple viewholders

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-viewholder

So I have `ViewHolders` `title` and `description`, and clicking them will do the exact same thing. The `setOnClickListener` methods are defined inside this method:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        // does A
    });
    holder.description.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // does A
    });
}
```

Is there another way to do it aside from extending from an abstract class?

Comment: Make a container for yours views, as a part of your holder, and apply the click listener on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't write OnClickListner in onBindViewHolder method as it will called every time when you scroll list

you have to make it in viewholder class

```
public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        TextView tv_desc, tv_title;

        public PlanetViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tv_desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_desc);
            tv_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

            //your code of on click
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: dont create `new View.OnClickListener()` just implement `View.OnClickListener` interface in the `CustomViewHolder` class